# Why is $f(X - Z)$ not dense in $Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$

This is from *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* by Qing Liu.  $X_{\eta} = X \times_Y \Spec \kappa(\eta) $ is the fiber of $f$ at $\eta$.  If $U$ is open in $X$, $U$ is said to dominate $Y$ if the image of $U$ is dense in $Y$.

[image]

I don't understand why $X \setminus Z$ does not dominate $Y$.  The only relevant information I can see is that the image of $X \setminus Z$ does not contain the unique generic point of $Y$.  Isn't it possible for a subset of an irreducible scheme to be dense without containing the unique generic point?

For example, $S = \Spec \mathbb{Z} \setminus (0)$ is dense in $\Spec \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You're right, it's possible for a subset of an irreducible scheme to be dense without containing a generic point. However, to check if the restriction to $X\setminus Z$ is dominant one can use [this Stacks Project lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RL). Of course, one needs to add to this the assumption $f$ is quasi-compact. Alternatively one can add a finite presentation hypothesis and use Chevalley's theorem to get the same result...

Comment: Thank you, I think finite presentation is a fairly mild assumption and I'm okay with going that route.  I think quasicompact is a pretty big restriction though.  Should this proposition be true in the generality it's stated?

Comment: I don't think so but I'm having a difficult time coming up with a counterexample.